# writing SQL case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, case

I have two tables on which i have performed inner join. I have a scenario where i need to fetch values from the first table based on the two conditions.

My query is

```
SELECT rm.ROUTE_ID
            , rm.ROUTE_CODE
            , rm.START_PLACE_ID
            , rm.END_PLACE_ID
            , rm.IS_ACTIVE
            , rm.LINKED_ROUTE
        FROM OPRS_ROUTE_MASTER rm
        INNER JOIN OPRS_ROUTE_HALTS rh
            ON rh.ROUTE_ID = rm.ROUTE_ID
        WHERE rh.PLACE_ID  = '51'
```

now i need to have two more conditions in the where clause.

```
case 1: when rm.START_PLACE_ID > 0 then i need to append AND rm.START_PLACE_ID to where clause

case 2: when rm.END_PLACE_ID > 0 then i need to append AND rm.START_PLACE_ID to where clause
```

if both are greater than zero then i need to append both the cases to the where clause.

Can some one please help me

Comment: no pranay, this is related to a search query. It is not necessary to always have values of start_place and end_place. If we have values greater then the search should be based on those values. it works fine if alll the 3 values are specified. if i search only based on the place id it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set the query up something like this:

```
select rm.ROUTE_ID       ,
       rm.ROUTE_CODE     ,
       rm.START_PLACE_ID ,
       rm.END_PLACE_ID   ,
       rm.IS_ACTIVE      ,
       rm.LINKED_ROUTE
from OPRS_ROUTE_MASTER rm
join OPRS_ROUTE_HALTS  rh on rh.ROUTE_ID = rm.ROUTE_ID
                         and rh.PLACE_ID = '51'
where rm.START_PLACE_ID = case when rm.START_PLACE_ID > 0 then @myStartPlaceID else rm.START_PLACE_ID end
  and rm.END_PLACE_ID   = case when rm.END_PLACE_ID   > 0 then @myEndPlaceID   else rm.END_PLACE_ID   end
```

If the table row has a positive value in the desired column (`START_PLACE_ID` or `END_PLACE_ID`), the column is compared to the desired value, otherwise it's compared to itself.

This avoids the use of alternation (the `OR` operator): using `OR` can degrade the execution plan, forcing a table or index scan rather than a seek.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something in your requirements, you can just add another `WHERE` filter using an `OR` or `AND`

```
SELECT rm.ROUTE_ID
    , rm.ROUTE_CODE
    , rm.START_PLACE_ID
    , rm.END_PLACE_ID
    , rm.IS_ACTIVE
    , rm.LINKED_ROUTE
FROM OPRS_ROUTE_MASTER rm
INNER JOIN OPRS_ROUTE_HALTS rh
    ON rh.ROUTE_ID = rm.ROUTE_ID
WHERE rh.PLACE_ID  = '51'
OR (or AND)
(
    (rm.START_PLACE_ID > 0 OR rm.END_PLACE_ID > 0)
    AND rm.START_PLACE_ID = yourValue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
SELECT rm.route_id, 
       rm.route_code, 
       rm.start_place_id, 
       rm.end_place_id, 
       rm.is_active, 
       rm.linked_route 
FROM   oprs_route_master rm 
       INNER JOIN oprs_route_halts rh 
               ON rh.route_id = rm.route_id 
WHERE  rh.place_id = '51' 
       AND ( rm.start_place_id <= 0 
              OR RM.start_place_id = xxx ) 
       AND ( rm.end_place_id <= 0 
              OR RM.start_place_id = yyy )
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: the AND statement should be appended only if the value is greater than zero. since i get the value sometimes as zero, the query retrieves no records. this works fine when i have all the 3 values route_id , start_place_id and end_place_id

Comment: That is essentially what I have done. Notice the OR Tests,and that the comparisons are reversed...  Taking the start_place_id for example - the value of start_place_id is irrelevant if the first test result matches. Not sure you've really specified the where clause in enough detail either...